# How to work with android camera app using external/internal storage?

Tags: android, android-camera, storage, android-camera-intent, camera-api

I am working on android camera app in which i have to capture selfie image/video and send to the server. I have used intent to open the camera. I have implemented the code at below but this code is working fine for those devices who have external storage but for those devices who have no external storage, app has stooped working at this line of code Environment.getExternalStorageState().
 Please give me suggestions how i can complete my scenario?

```
private static final int PICK_FILE_REQUEST = 1;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private String selectedFilePath;
ImageView bimage, bvideo;
ArrayList imageList;
TextView bimage_gallery, bvideo_gallery;
//ProgressDialog dialog;
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
String flag_value, thumbnail, email;
private static final String EXTRA_FILENAME = "com.commonsware.android.camcon.EXTRA_FILENAME";
private static final String FILENAME = "CameraContentDemo.jpeg";
private static final int CONTENT_REQUEST = 1337;
private File output = null;
private Uri outputUri = null;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
Uri fileUri;
int dialog_nbr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    isFrstAttemp();
    occupyFullScreen();
    setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);
    getRefereces();
}

// is this first attemp of user, please first register yourself
public void isFrstAttemp() {
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("filter", MODE_PRIVATE);
    email = mSharedPreferences.getString("isRegistered", "no");
    if (email.equals("no")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUp.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}

//set full screen
public void occupyFullScreen() {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}

//get references
public void getRefereces() {
    bimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camera);
    bvideo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.videos);
    bimage_gallery = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.img_gallery);
    bvideo_gallery = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.videos_gallery);
    bimage.setOnClickListener(this);
    bimage_gallery.setOnClickListener(this);
    bvideo_gallery.setOnClickListener(this);
    bvideo.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageList = new ArrayList<>();
}

// Create a file Uri for saving an image or video
private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    if (getOutputMediaFile(type)==null){
        dialog_nbr=6;
        storageProblem();
        return null;
    }
    else{
        Uri path= Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
        return path;
    }
}

private File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.
    if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        return mediaFile;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.camera:
            imageCapture();
            break;
        case R.id.videos:
            videocapture();
            break;
        case R.id.img_gallery:
            if (haveNetworkConnection()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Gallery_images.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                dialog_nbr=1;
                openDialog();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.videos_gallery:
            if (haveNetworkConnection()) {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Gallery_videos.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
            } else {
                dialog_nbr=1;
                openDialog();
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable(EXTRA_FILENAME, output);
}

public void imageCapture() {
    flag_value = "1";
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    if (fileUri!=null) {
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CONTENT_REQUEST);
    }
}

private void videocapture() {
    flag_value = "2";
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 10);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (haveNetworkConnection()) {
            if (requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST) {
                if (data == null) {
                    return;
                }
                PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
                wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
                wakeLock.acquire();
                Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
                selectedFilePath = FilePath.getPath(this, selectedFileUri);
                if (flag_value == "2") {
                    Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(selectedFilePath,
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
                    flag_value = getStringImage(thumb);
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Selected File Path:" + selectedFilePath);
                if (selectedFilePath != null) {
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                uploadFile(selectedFilePath);
                            } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Insufficient Memory!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                                // dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please choose a File First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else if (requestCode == CONTENT_REQUEST) {
                PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
                wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
                wakeLock.acquire();
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            //creating new thread to handle Http Operations
                            uploadFile(fileUri.getPath());
                        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    dialog_nbr=2;
                                    openDialog();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else {
            dialog_nbr=1;
            openDialog();
        }
    }
}

public int uploadFile(final String selectedFilePath) {
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);
    String[] parts = selectedFilePath.split("/");
    if (!selectedFile.isFile()) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "suurce file does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return 0;
    } else {
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
            URL url = new URL(Constant.SERVER_URL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
            connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty(
                    "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", selectedFilePath);
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\"" + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                try {
                    dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                    dialog_nbr=2;
                    openDialog();
                }
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"email\"" + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(email);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"flag\"" + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(flag_value);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            // get server ok responce
            try {
                serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                dialog_nbr=2;
                openDialog();
            }
            //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                // imageList.add(selectedFilePath);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                    }
                });
            }
            //reading server echo responce
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dialog_nbr=4;
                    openDialog();
                }
            });
            //closing the input and output streams
            fileInputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();
            if (wakeLock.isHeld()) {
                wakeLock.release();
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "URL Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                }
            });
        }
        return serverResponseCode;
    }
}

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}

private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}

public void openDialog() {
    View dialogView=null;
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    if (dialog_nbr==1)
        dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_connection, null);
    else if (dialog_nbr==2){
        dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_insufficeint_memory, null);
    }
    else if (dialog_nbr==3){
        dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_server_error, null);
    }
    else if (dialog_nbr==4){
        dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_file_uploaded, null);
    }
    else if (dialog_nbr==5){
        dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_exit, null);
    }
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
    final AlertDialog findMeDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    findMeDialog.show();
    LinearLayout reset_btn = (LinearLayout) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.ok);
    reset_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            findMeDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}

public void storageProblem(){
    View dialogView=null;
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_external_storage_error, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
    final AlertDialog findMeDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    findMeDialog.show();
    LinearLayout reset_btn = (LinearLayout) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.ok);
    reset_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            findMeDialog.dismiss();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    dialog_nbr=3;
    View dialogView=null;
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_exit, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
    final AlertDialog findMeDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    findMeDialog.show();
    TextView cancel_btn = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    TextView exit_btn = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.exit);
    cancel_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            findMeDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    exit_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            findMeDialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

This code is working fine on my device but App is crashing when my client is testing on huawei p9 lite at  `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` it's saying you have not mounted the sd card. please give me a solution how this code will worik fine for those devices who have not external storage

Comment: "i am getting error" -- if you are crashing, please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace. If you are not crashing, please explain in detail what "getting error" means.

Comment: Do you have the right permissions to read the state?

Comment: @CommonsWare i have edited the question and i have pasted all the code please give me suggestion .

Comment: @doron Yakovlev yes i have all the permissions

Comment: I repeat: if you are crashing, please edit your question and **post the entire Java stack trace**. If you are not crashing, **please explain in detail what "getting error" means**.

Comment: actually the problem is this ,  this code is working properly on my device but when i send the apk to my client then he say app is crashing when i captured image and press ok

Comment: my scenario is so simple , i want to capture image through camera and upload to the server ..